# Do I need to feed my cow every single day?

Tags: story-of-seasons

I noticed that I put fodder down for my cow, and there was still fodder there the next day. Do I need to feed them every day? The farm guide says that a fodder is good for 10. Does that mean it will feed 1 animal for 10 days (or 2 for 5, or 10 for one, etc.) or should I be putting down fresh every day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 piece of fodder is good for 10 feedings. That means if you only have one animal, it will last for 10 days. Once you get a horse, 1 piece of fodder will last 5 days, so on and so forth.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought, but since the Animal Notebook had a picture of fodder that was still greyed out, it made me worried she wasn't getting enough food or something.

Comment: if it's greyed out that just means they haven't eaten yet.